# How to change these codes using struct to class in C++?

Tags: c++

I have these chunk of codes and i want to use class instead of struct.How should i modify my codes?

```
 struct node
 {
     int number;        /* data portion */
     node* next; /* pointer portion */
 };

node* create_node(int number, node* next)
{
    node* result = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    result->number = number;
    result->next = next;
    return result;
}

void destroy_node(node* const list)
{
    free(list);
}
```

Am i supposed to do something like this?:

```
class node{
public:
   create_node(int number,node* next){
       //blah blah
    }
    destroy_node(node* const list){
       //blah blah
     }

}
```

Comment: Look into the topic of classes and constructors and destructors...

Comment: The only difference between `class` and `struct` is members in `struct` are public by default and `class` are private

Comment: Note that `struct` and `class` are exactly the same thing in C++ (except that by default without access specifier things are `public` when using `struct` and `private` when using `class`). Both define *class types*.

Comment: Your functions in the last code block are also lacking return types, if they are not supposed to be constructor and destructor.

Comment: Yes im aware i need to add in default constructor and destructor..but im not sure the functions create_node and destroy_node should be moved inside the class as well?

Comment: @SoulessNight These functions have the same purpose as constructor and destructor would have, so they are not needed anymore. Also please don't use `malloc`/`free` in C++ code. Use `new`/`delete` or even better `std::vector`.

Comment: Yeah i realised that they were acting similar to constructor and destructor im just not sure if i have to rename them example ~node for destructor or if its okay to just use destroy_node

Comment: If you are not sure what you are supposed to do how can we help?

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to write "use `std::unique_ptr`", not "use `std::vector`" for your particular case here, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

What's the purpose of change though? blind conversion from C to C++ is mighty pointless.

If your purpose is to create OOP-based linked list, you should start from something like this:

```
class LinkedList 
{
   struct node {
      value_type value;
      node *next, *prev;
   };
   node *head; // maybe *last too, to avoid O(n) complexity of adding new element.
public:
   LinkedList() : head (nullptr) {}

   // methods for manipulation with list, 
   // maybe definition of iterator type for such.

   ~ LinkedList(); // should dispose of all nodes created
};
```

You must encapsulate whole container, not individual nodes. And of course, list can be easily templated by making `value_type` a template parameter.

Logic behind C and C++ code are different in principle. Note, that struct is a class, even if it doesn't have a constructor, a destructor or virtual methods. In that case it would be a trivial class. A trivial class with standard memory layout is  compatible with C struct.

Nested class node  may use RAII concept

```
class LinkedList 
{
   struct node
   {
      value_type value;
      node *next, *prev;

      node(value_type v, node *pr) : 
           value(v), next(nullptr), prev(pr) { pr->next = this; }

      // inserting constructor
      node(value_type v, node *pr,  node *nx) : 
           value(v), next(nx), prev(pr) { pr->next = this; }

      ~node()
      { 
         delete next; // would call ~node() of next node if next non-null 
      }
   };
```

Then to create first node with value `val` in list you would do

```
   head = new node(val, nullptr); // no previous nodes
```

To insert node between nodes pointed by  `node1` and `node1->next`

```
   new node(val, node1, node1->next);
```

And destructor of list would be

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
   delete head;
}
```

While my example is the more commonly used doubly-linked list, it's applicable to your one-way linked list, by excluding manipulation with `prev` member variable. While classic concept of linked list doesn't allow to determine if you're at head of list but only if you're at its tail, in case of such encapsulation you still can do that by comparing pointer to node with `head` pointer.